# Xaml MediaElement does not play .mov video from internet

Tags: c#, xaml, video-streaming, uwp

I want to play live video stream from internet providing an url to `MediaElement` xaml control. Everything work's fine if the video is `.mp4`. But if the video was taken on iphone and saved as `.mov` then `MediaElement` show's nothing and only `loading` event is fired. (~5min after download completed other events firing too)
Here `MediaElement` initialisation:

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
media.MediaFailed += Media_MediaFailed;
media.PartialMediaFailureDetected += Media_PartialMediaFailureDetected;
media.MediaOpened += Media_MediaOpened;
media.DownloadProgressChanged += Media_DownloadProgressChanged;
media.Loading += Media_Loading;
media.MediaEnded += Media_MediaEnded;
media.Source = new Uri(URL);
```

If download video manually via `HttpClient` and then provide `Stream.AsRamdomAccessStream()` to `MediaElement`, video starts playing immediately. It seems like `MediaElement` does not support live streaming for .mov/quicktime videos. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was in the order of container atoms. As explained [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/mobile_progressive_playback/index.php)

> In order to start playing a movie file right away its metadata contained in the "moov" atom is paramount to the player. If the movie file atoms are ordered as previously described everything work as expected...but most video editors (ffmpeg, quicktime, flash video) generate atoms in the wrong order (as seen on the right): With the "moov" atom last.

And provided solution:

> The only solution is to fix those files and reorder the atoms inside. This can be done:
>
> - Oldskool way using some C code from FFMPEG's qt-faststart.c. The code moves the "moov" atom at the top of the file and update all the "stco" sub-atoms pointers by adding the proper offset.
> - Using iOS AV Foundation framework and a few lines of Objective-C (you can also convert from MOV to MP4 since Android cannot read MOV):
>
>   ```
>   #import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>
>   #import <AVFoundation/AVAssetExportSession.h>
>   #import <AVFoundation/AVMediaFormat.h>
>
>   + (void) convertVideoToMP4AndFixMooV: (NSString*)filename toPath:(NSString*)outputPath
>   {    
>
>   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finename];    
>   AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
>
>
>   AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
>                                      exportSessionWithAsset:avAsset
>                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
>
>   exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
>   exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V;   
>
>
>   // This should move the moov atom before the mdat atom,
>   // hence allow playback before the entire file is downloaded
>   exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;     
>
>
>   [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
>   ^{
>       if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {} 
>         else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {
>             NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
>         } 
>         else 
>         {
>             NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %d", exportSession.status);
>         }
>    }];
>   }
>   ```

As I also developing an iOS client, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mov` is not supported by the built-in `MediaElement` control.

`mov` video type is proprietary format by Apple Inc. for the QuickTime player, which means it will probably never be supported natively.

The complete list of supported formats and codecs is [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs).

**Edit:** It seems the `MediaElement` control can actually use installed codecs on the PC to play directly unsupported formats, including `mov`.

Comment: But I can play local mov videos with `MediaElement`, as well as pre-downloaded mov videos. The only problem is with live streaming. Or do you mean that streaming is not supported?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case I am not really sure... The `mov` is just a compression around `mp4` so the `MediaElement` might be able to play it using the installed codecs on your PC, but will not be able to play it streamed. I also think on Phone or Xbox the `mov` wouldn't play at all, even from file, isn't that true?

Comment: I did not check on phones an xbox because I write only desktop client, but it looks like you are right. Also I have problems with opening `mov` videos via html5 in chrome browser, but this finding is for another question.